# C# - Add button click events using code

Tags: c#, winforms, button, for-loop, textbox

I have almost 0 experience with C# and programming overall, so you might find my question stupid. However, Im trying to create a Windows Form using code and I've succeeded with what I've wanted. But now I would like to add button click events to all my buttons. I want addToDay[i] to clear text in exerciseBox[i], setBox[i] and repBox[i]. Thanks.

```
    public NewSchedule2(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        labels = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[7];
        exercises = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        sets = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        reps = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        addToDay = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[7];

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            this.labels[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 40 + i * 50);
            this.labels[i].Name = "Label" + i;
            this.labels[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 20);
            this.labels[i].Text = lines[i];
            this.Controls.Add(this.labels[i]);

            if (lines[i] == "Restday")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                this.exercises[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.exercises[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 40 + i * 50);
                this.exercises[i].Name = "excersiceBox" + i;
                this.exercises[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 20);
                this.exercises[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.exercises[i]);

                this.sets[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.sets[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(290, 40 + i * 50);
                this.sets[i].Name = "setBox" + i;
                this.sets[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
                this.sets[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.sets[i]);

                this.reps[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.reps[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(350, 40 + i * 50);
                this.reps[i].Name = "repBox" + i;
                this.reps[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
                this.reps[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.reps[i]);

                this.addToDay[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.addToDay[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(430, 40 + i * 50);
                this.addToDay[i].Name = "addToDay" + i;
                this.addToDay[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Clicked);
                this.addToDay[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
                this.addToDay[i].Text = "Add To " + lines[i];
                this.Controls.Add(this.addToDay[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You could have just googled "c# events".

Comment: as i said, im pretty new to C# and therefor don't know what to search for. Could you please be so kind and link me to a tutorial which would actually help me?

Comment: Before to ask questions it is always better to try a simple search first. For example: [search "add click event to button" on google](https://www.google.it/search?q=c%23+add+click+event&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:it:official&client=firefox-a#gs_rn=14&gs_ri=psy-ab&pq=c%23%20add%20click%20event&cp=20&gs_id=f&xhr=t&q=c%23+add+click+event+to+button&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=firefox-a&hs=0NH&rls=org.mozilla:it%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=c%23+add+click+event+t&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.ZG4&fp=afb44d2daa2cf166&biw=1366&bih=639)

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/button read this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx is the first google result for "c# events".

Comment: pretty new to C# is not a good reason not to google, :)

Comment: Stack overflow wasn't around when I started to program .. Google was the only way forward ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is how you can add click events for buttons:

```
// btnTest is object of button. This is how you add event for button
btnTest.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnButton_Click);

// its event handler

void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // your code goes here
}
```

I hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is it a sample of what you could use in order to accomplish that.
I wish you an happy learning :)

```
   public NewSchedule2(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        labels = new System.Windows.Forms.Label[7];
        exercises = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        sets = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        reps = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[7];
        addToDay = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[7];

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            this.labels[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.labels[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 40 + i * 50);
            this.labels[i].Name = "Label" + i;
            this.labels[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 20);
            this.labels[i].Text = lines[i];
            this.Controls.Add(this.labels[i]);

            if (lines[i] == "Restday")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                this.exercises[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.exercises[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 40 + i * 50);
                this.exercises[i].Name = "excersiceBox" + i;
                this.exercises[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 20);
                this.exercises[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.exercises[i]);

                this.sets[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.sets[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(290, 40 + i * 50);
                this.sets[i].Name = "setBox" + i;
                this.sets[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
                this.sets[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.sets[i]);

                this.reps[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.reps[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(350, 40 + i * 50);
                this.reps[i].Name = "repBox" + i;
                this.reps[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
                this.reps[i].Text = "";
                this.Controls.Add(this.reps[i]);

                this.addToDay[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.addToDay[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(430, 40 + i * 50);
                this.addToDay[i].Name = "addToDay" + i;
                this.addToDay[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Clicked);
                this.addToDay[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
                this.addToDay[i].Text = "Add To " + lines[i];
                this.addToDay[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Clicked);
                this.Controls.Add(this.addToDay[i]);
            }
        }
    }

   private void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button triggeredButton = (Button) sender;

        var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*[ _]?)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
        var match = numAlpha.Match(triggeredButton.Name);
        var num = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;

        this.exercises[num].Text = string.Empty;
        this.sets[num].Text = string.Empty;
        this.reps[num].Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple way to set custom event for each your buttons:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
     .
     .
     .
     string text = "some things...";
     this.addToDay[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.addToDay[i].Click += (object sender, EventArgs e)=>
     {
        //you can use your variables inside event
        MessageBox.ShowDialog(text + i);
     };
 }
```