# How would one add code to a control that was added programmatically to a windows form application in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I very new to C# and I would like to add a Button to a form programmatically. When this button is pressed I want it to run some code (like a normal button woukd work). But, everywhere I have searched only shows how to add the button and not how to add code to the button.

Comment: `var button = new Button(); button.Click += (s, args) => { doSomething(); doSomethingElseAfterdoSomething(); }`

Comment: i've been trying to add this button to a tab. Would the code need to change to make it appear in the tab?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you add it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Add button click events using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807608/c-sharp-add-button-click-events-using-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to give the button a name property, then in your code you "refer" to the button by it's name like so:

```
void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // your code goes here
}
```

where btnButton_Click is the name of the button.