# How can i trigger a click event at a Button which has no name

Tags: c#

In my code the buttons are made automatically and I need to save the information from the button in the click event. I am coding a ShopSystem in WindowsForms and when I click a button (should also work like clicking 3 times) it should stand in a text box at the next form but I just need help at coding the clickevent.

```
while (id < artikelAnzahl)
{
    Button ArtikelID = new Button
    {
        Location = new Point(posX, posY),
        Size = new Size(100, 75),
    };
    posX += 120;
    double s = double.Parse(id.ToString()) / 5;

    if (int.TryParse(s.ToString(), out int i))
    {
        posY += 100;
        posX = 70;
    }
    this.Controls.Add(ArtikelID);

    foreach (var p in xmlArtikelliste.Descendants("Artikel"))
    {
        if (int.Parse(p.Attribute("ID").Value) == id)
        {
            ArtikelID.Text = p.Element("Name").Value + " " +
                p.Element("Preis").Value + "€ " +
                p.Element("Anzahl").Value + "Stk. ";
        }
    }
    id++; 
}
```

Comment: You just want to create a click event.  Does this answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807608/c-sharp-add-button-click-events-using-code   ?

Comment: Event handlers aren't created by name. Have you tried adding an event handler? `myButton.Click+=new EventHandler(...);`

Comment: @BuhBuh I can´t take a normal click event because my buttons have no name. I take the information out of a xml file. There is a list of things you can buy and i need to find another way to make a click event.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is my problem, "myButton" my Buttons have no names, i have ID´s in my xml list and i can´t do it like this.

Comment: I don't understand.  You do have a reference to the button.  It's the variable `ArtikelID`

Comment: What does XML have to do with creating an event handler for a button? Are you trying to generate buttons and textboxes dynamically from XML data? That's very different from what you asked

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes sorry, I am not that good in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Adding Click event delegate will not do the trick since the buttons are generated in a `while loop` and the event handler's action will always have the values from the last loop iteration.

So, you can achieve what you need with the following:

- Button's Tag property for storing the data

You can store Article ID from xmlArtikelliste.Descendants("Artikel"), or the whole article if you will:

```
ArtikelID.Tag = p.Attribute("ID")
```

- Event handler which will be added to the Button's Click event.

Sample code:

```
ArtikelID.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(sender is Button button)
    {
        // Pass button.Tag.ToString() as parameter when navigating to the other form;
    }
};
```

You can read more about it on the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click?view=netframework-4.8).

Complete code:

```
while (id < artikelAnzahl)
{
    Button ArtikelID = new Button
    {
        Location = new Point(posX, posY),
        Size = new Size(100, 75),
    };
    posX += 120;
    double s = double.Parse(id.ToString()) / 5;

    if (int.TryParse(s.ToString(), out int i))
    {
        posY += 100;
        posX = 70;
    }
    this.Controls.Add(ArtikelID);

    foreach (var p in xmlArtikelliste.Descendants("Artikel"))
    {
        if (int.Parse(p.Attribute("ID").Value) == id)
        {
            ArtikelID.Text = p.Element("Name").Value + " " +
                p.Element("Preis").Value + "€ " +
                p.Element("Anzahl").Value + "Stk. ";

            ArtikelID.Tag = p.Attribute("ID");
        }
    }

    ArtikelID.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (sender is Button button && button.Tag != null)
        {
            // Pass button.Tag.ToString() as parameter when navigating to the other form;
        }
    };

    id++;
}
```

Edit 1:
`(sender, e)` is a standard delegate signature for event handlers which executes an `Action`.

Ideally, what you could do is create a list of buttons, add button template and bind the data received from xmlArtikell to it. You can have a look at the following introductory [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f7IoKQIraQ) on data binding in Win Forms.

Edit 2: Added solution to store the data in Button's Tag property, so it can be utilized later in the Click event handler. Otherwise, the action will always have the last while loop iteration variables to work with.

Comment: Thank you that helped me.But i want to have the Ability to click multiple times like adding 2 carrots then 3 sausages and then i want to click on a button "next page"

Comment: This is completely different topic than the question asked. 
Please mark an answer as accepted for this question and post a new one and we'll try to help.
Additionally, it would be good to show that you've done some research on the topic before posting a question.

Comment: Another thing, is it mandatory that you develop this ShopSystem in `WinForms`?
`WPF` is a much better and modern alternative to `WinForms`.
I'd suggest to have a look at `WPF` and if possible switch to it.

Comment: I am at work in learning the job and thats a must, also it is my first month.

Comment: All clear, good luck with it!
 I'd strongly recommend going through fundamental C# tutorials, in parallel with WinForms tutorials, will help you a lot.